# UK house purchase lawyer not answering timeline/status questions

Tags: united-kingdom, lawyer, professional-ethics

In the process on buying a property and apparently there is a mistake in the lease document and it has to be amended. Also I asked several time if there are other things to do in order to close the deal (mortgage deed, purchase document etc.)  and I never had a clear answer. Now I asked several time : if something else is still to be done, the approximate timeline, when the search has been submitted, when the lease document has been submitted for variation etc. None of these questions had an answer which means I cannot plan anything in terms of timeline. The whole process is essentially a 'black-box' between the 2 lawyers (buyer and seller) with no precise information given to the client.

I am surprised that the lawyer can avoid answering questions and treat the whole process as their matter which the client should not have an understanding on the actual situation.

Is that normal? Is this the right way  conveyancing is performed?

Comment: Note that, particularly with conveyancing, your solicitor is often as in the dark as you are because the other side is withholding information (often as a tactic because delay is beneficial to them in some way). But that shouldn't stop your solicitor from telling you as much, and certainly some of the things you've mentioned (e.g. searches) are within your solicitor's control.

Answer (score 2):

All solicitors are required to have an internal complaints process, so if you have an issue with the service provided you should register a formal complaint with the firm. If that doesn't solve it, the next step is to go to the [Legal Ombudsman](https://www.legalombudsman.org.uk/information-centre/consumer-resources/complaining-to-a-service-provider/) - or to the Solicitors Regulation Authority (SRA) if there's a suspected breach of their [Code of Conduct](https://www.sra.org.uk/solicitors/standards-regulations/code-conduct-solicitors/).

[This link](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/en/public/for-public-visitors/using-a-solicitor/complain-about-a-solicitor) may assist also.